# Get tag if src have value

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this:

```
/\<img[\s\S]*url.com[\s\S]*?\/>/g
```

So I need remove img, if src have special url, but problem with html like this:

```
<img src="pofig.com/adfg"/>
<p>Text text text</p>
<img src="url.com/asfsdf/sdf"/>
```

Will be remove all tags, but I need only last img tag.

Example - https://regex101.com/r/4qjF0g/1

Comment: What pattern are you trying to match? What is "special url"?

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/5MMzb6/1) better ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub It looks like yes,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `[\s\S]` which means *anything* you can use `[^>]`:

```
\<img[^>]*url.com[\s\S]*?\/>
```

See it [live](https://regex101.com/r/5MMzb6/1)

Answer (score -1):

This should be enough, I guess.

```
\<img .*url.com.*?\/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('src').indexOf('imgur') != -1){
      $(this).css('opacity', 0.3);
    }
  });
});
```

See [example](http://jsbin.com/nekuqek/edit?js,output).